# Would using a built in arrays within a class definition, but with size deferred to derived class cause hiding?

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

Every class within the tree depends has-a relationship with other classes for monitoring voltage and current sensors (which are usually named 1,2,3...). The problem is that how many of these sensors there are depends on what type of unit is being simulated; meaning only the derived classes will know that.

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public: 
     A() {};
     virtual void Display() = 0;
protected:
     int array[]; // size is purposefully left out in base class
};

class B : public A {
public:
     B(int numbers[4]);
     virtual void Display();
protected:
     int array[4]; // 4 sensors are required, number fixed at compile time
}

B::B(int numbers[4]) {
     for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
          array[i] = numbers[i];
}

void B::Display() {
     cout << " B numbers are: ";
     for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
          cout << array[i] << " ";
     cout << endl;
}

class C : public A {
public: 
     C(int numbers[8]);
     virtual void Display();
protected:
     int array[8]; // 8 sensors needed, number fixed at compile time
};

C::C(int numbers[8]) {
     for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
          array[i] = numbers[i];
}

void C::Display() {
     cout << " C numbers are: ";
     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
          cout << array[i] << " ";
     cout << endl;
}
```

This driver shows that this will technically work when using the g++ compiler, but I fear that I may have data hiding by redeclaring array in B and C classes.

```
main() {
    int B_numbers[] = {1,2,,3,4};
    int C_numbers[] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    B b(B_numbers[]);
    C c(C_numbers[]);
    b.Display();
    c.Display();
}
```

And thank you for any suggestions anyone is able to provide.

Comment: You can't override member data (you're creating independent arrays). `int array[];` is zero-sized array. Time to look into templates.

Comment: Your first problem is that zero length arrays are not permitted in C++ so the GCC extension that this is not considered portable.

Comment: consider adding a virtual function to the base class, `virtual int* Array()`, which derived classes implement returning a pointer to their array.

Comment: I have been looking at using either std:;array or std::vector and thus far prefer the former, because the size is fixed at compile time. Would using std::array still allow me to defer stating the size of the array until the derived classes?

Comment: @Cam2025 You can't defer the size of the class until some subsequent definition, so it's not possible to defer sizing of or virtualize members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in any of the code you displayed uses `A::array`, so you can just remove it as being unnecessary. `B` and `C` just have their own personal arrays that their respective overrides of `Display()` know what to do with - `A` doesn't need to be involved here. Just have:

```
struct A {
    virtual void Display() = 0;
};
```

---

Note that `B(int numbers[4]);` isn't actually any different from `B(int *numbers)` as far as constructors go, the number there is just giving the illusion of safety - I can easily pass wrong-sized arrays into there. For that reason, prefer to use `std::array` - which has the added benefit of being copy-constructible:

```
class B : public A {
public:
     B (std::array<int, 4> const& arr)
     : array(arr)
     { }

     virtual void Display();
protected:
     std::array<int, 4> array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions can be made 'virtual', meaning that the actual function called will be determined for a given object by looking it up in the object's vtable.  This is how overloading works. An object instantiated for a derived class will have a vtable pointing to the derived functions.

C++ doesn't do that for data members. Your derived class's data members are different from the base members. If you try to access the array, which one you select will be based upon the type of the variable pointing to the object, *not* the type of the object itself. And that **is not a good thing**.

> C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off. —Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ

Comment: A definite concern as the hierarchy will have 3 levels when it is done, the base class, the intermediate classes in which the sizes of the arrays becomes known, and then "leaf" classes with configuration specific tweaks to various virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from using a templated approach to provide an *array* in the base class that derived classes can use and define the size of at compile time.

Something like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
class A
{
public:
    A(): arr{} {}
    A(const std::array<int, N>& arr): arr{arr} {}

    virtual ~A() = default; // needs virtual destructor

    void Display() const // doesn't need to be virtual
    {
        for(auto n: arr) // generic code
            std::cout << n << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    int Get(size_t n) const { return arr.at(n); }
    void Set(size_t n, int value) { arr.at(n) = value; }

protected:
    std::array<int, N> arr;
};

class B: public A<4>
{
public:
    B(const std::array<int, 4>& numbers): A(numbers) {}
};

class C: public A<8>
{
public:
    C(const std::array<int, 8>& numbers): A(numbers) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> B_numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    B b(B_numbers);
    C c({5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12});

    b.Display();
    c.Display();
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

The benefit of this approach is that by writing generic functions in the base class (that rely only on the properties of the `std::array` class like `arr.size()` and *iterators*) you can save time creating similar classes which differ only on the size.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could go about this.

When you declared `array[]` as protected in the base class, it means all the derived classes have access to it (so you don't have to redefine it).

If you want to be certain that your data is always as intended, you could remove the additional `array` definitions, as they create ambiguity (you have a base class and derived class member with the same name), and declare the intended size of the array as a protected variable, which you can then assign in each derived class' constructor.

An alternative way you could code this would be with vectors, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public: 
        A() {};
        virtual void Display() = 0;
    protected:
        vector<int> array;
        int size;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B(int *numbers);
        virtual void Display();
};

B::B(int *numbers) {
    size=4;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        array.push_back(numbers[i]);
}

void B::Display() {
    cout << " B numbers are: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

class C : public A {
    public: 
        C(int *numbers);
        virtual void Display();
};

C::C(int *numbers) {
    size=8;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        array.push_back(numbers[i]);
}

void C::Display() {
    cout << " C numbers are: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    int B_numbers[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int C_numbers[] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    B b(B_numbers);
    C c(C_numbers);
    b.Display();
    c.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

This way you only declare the size in one place per class (the constructor), and there's only one possible container which can hold your data in your objects. You also don't have to worry about memory management.

If you want to go the extra mile, you could use vectors (and iterators) everywhere, this would ensure that the size of your input always matches the size of your storage.